# Why is asigning a dynamic to a non-nullable not an error with sound null safety

Tags: dart, nullable, static-analysis

In dart with sound null safety turned on it is entirely possible to do

```dart
dynamic myVar; // myVar assumes default value of null
String someString = myVar; // No warning by IDE.
```

As expected the above results in a run-time error since `myVar` is null and `someString` is non-nullable.

Is this a problem with the linter/IDE?

I did discover that I can enable pedantic linting that causes the IDE to show a warning when I try to implicitly cast dynamic to another type.  Turning that on helps but I think the problem is that dynamic can be null without having to be explicitly defined as nullable.

In short we don't have

```dart
dynamic? myNullableVar;
```

My questions is:  Is this a bug?

This "issue" bites you most commonly when you do something like

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> myData = jsonDecode(receivedResponseBody);
var name = myData['name'];
```

In the above example I expect the IDE to show a warning that I am trying to assign a potentially null value to a non-nullable variable.  The IDE should require the user to add a null check.

If this is not a bug (in the IDE or in the linter), then why not?

Long story short:  The implicit cast from dynamic to another type masks the issue with null assignments, and I expect the IDE to provide a warning.

---

EDIT:  after note from @ jamesdlin below
Specifically I am OK with the following where the Left-hand side of the assignment allows null values.

```dart
dynamic someVar;
String? myString = someVar;
```

---

Side note, I was hoping that the new dart typeDef feature would allow my to build something similar to Union type hints in Python.  That would allow me to then get something like

```dart
typeDev JsonValueType = { int, String, float, bool };
```

And the result from jsonDecode would then be

`Map<String, JsonValueType?>`

Which explicitly includes Null and therefore the IDE would warn the user to add a null check.

*My opinion:  As long as you can assign any nullable type on the right of an assignment operator to a non-nullable type on the left, you don't have true sound null safety.*

Comment: You can disable this behavior which is (and you also calls it) "implicit casts": https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

Comment: I am aware of that, I should have linked the page. I think the issue of allowing implicit casts is a separate issue from allowing null on the right to be assigned to non-nullable on the left.

Comment: The entire point of using the `dynamic` type is to *disable static type checking*.  There's no reason to have a `dynamic?` type since `dynamic` can be anything (and the actual type will be known only at runtime).  If you want a non-nullable, universal base type, use `Object`, or if you want a nullable one, use `Object?`.

Comment: @jamesdlin that is a valid point, but my point is that static TYPE checking is not the same thing as checking for NULL assignments.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  The `null` assignment is checked at runtime, and using `dynamic` essentially means that you want runtime checks for everything.  I suppose arguably in your trivial example, the analyzer could determine that `myVar` is never assigned to and can never be anything but `null`, but in general, the static analyzer won't be able to protect you from assigning `dynamic` to non-nullable types unless you disable implicit casts from `dynamic`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Please See the comment I added in the EDIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug.

You can do:

```dart
dynamic x = "not an int";
int y = x;
```

and not get any compiler warnings. That's just how `dynamic` works, it turns off compiler ("static") type-checks and relies on run-time ("dynamic") checks instead. That's where the name comes from.

There is no reason to allow `dynamic?` because `dynamic` already allows the `null` value (and any other value). The `dynamic` type is *inherently nullable*, adding `?` to it makes no difference, just as `Null?` is meaningless.

The Dart type system is statically null sound (mostly, the usual caveats around generics apply), but `dynamic` is a way to turn that type system *off* on request. Don't use `dynamic` unless you want that effect.

Comment: I am about 90% inclined to accept this, because this also correlates with comments by other people.  One thing is still nigling.  

Is there a distinction between turning off type checking (by using dynamic) and turning off sound null validation that could negate this answer?

Comment: I think that the request to report an error (or a warning) for an unchecked `dynamic` => `T` assignment (in the same way that an error is reported for `T?` => `T` assignments) but not for `dynamic` => `T?` seems reasonable, although doing so would run counter to the traditional "`dynamic` disables all static type checks" philosophy.  If you want to pursue this further, it might be more productive to file an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/ for discussion with the Dart language team (of which lrn is already a member).

Comment: Using `dynamic` affects static checking, by inserting run-time checks instead. Turning off sound null safety turns off *some* runtime checks (or rather, modifies the checks to accept `null` even if the static type was non-nullable. Unsound null-safety is effectively null-safe static semantics with pre-null-safe runtime semantics (or a clever enough approximation which still understands the other new features) to make old code keep working the way it used to.
When your entire program is soundly null safe, that stops being a problem.